# Error with Contract, message: method is not found

Tags: rust, blockchain, nearprotocol

I just working with the "Quick-start Guide" in the last part "invoking methods" when i try to call any method always see the error:

```
Failure [xxxx.testnet]
Error: Contract method is not found
An error occured
Error: Contract method is not found
```

I have all the methods becase is only copy paste tutorial.

** UPDATE **

I just follow the steps.
Deploy is correct:

```
near deploy --wasmFile target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/rust_counter_tutorial.wasm --accountId josedlujan.testnet
```

The msg:

```
Starting deployment. Account id: josedlujan.testnet, node: https://rpc.testnet.near.org, helper: https://helper.testnet.near.org, file: target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/rust_counter_tutorial.wasm
Transaction Id 5LiJSuaso4XJ85gYcMopgECgAMvK4BxAHGgfTuGxYHAY
```

```
To see the transaction in the transaction explorer, please open this url in your browser
https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/5LiJSuaso4XJ85gYcMopgECgAMvK4BxAHGgfTuGxYHAY
```

But, when i execute methods.

```
near call josedlujan.testnet increment --accountId josedlujan.testnet
```

I always see:

```
Scheduling a call: josedlujan.testnet.increment()
Receipt: 7GsyvaVGErEr7rXkQdBQSu5F3FRFCQ2BG2LJuDT3t4Gx
    Failure [josedlujan.testnet]: Error: Contract method is not found
An error occured
Error: Contract method is not found
```

But i have the methods lib.rs:

````
pub fn increment(&mut self) {
        // note: adding one like this is an easy way to accidentally overflow
        // real smart contracts will want to have safety checks
        // e.g. self.val = i8::wrapping_add(self.val, 1);
        // https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i8.html#method.wrapping_add
        self.val += 1;
        let log_message = format!("Increased number to {}", self.val);
        env::log(log_message.as_bytes());
        after_counter_change();
    }

    /// Decrement (subtract from) the counter.
    ///
    /// In (/src/main.js) this is also added to the "changeMethods" array
    /// using near-cli we can call this by:
    ///
    /// ```bash
    /// near call counter.YOU.testnet decrement --accountId donation.YOU.testnet
    /// ```
    pub fn decrement(&mut self) {
        // note: subtracting one like this is an easy way to accidentally overflow
        // real smart contracts will want to have safety checks
        // e.g. self.val = i8::wrapping_sub(self.val, 1);
        // https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i8.html#method.wrapping_sub
        self.val -= 1;
        let log_message = format!("Decreased number to {}", self.val);
        env::log(log_message.as_bytes());
        after_counter_change();
    }
````

lib.rs

````
//! This contract implements simple counter backed by storage on blockchain.
//!
//! The contract provides methods to [increment] / [decrement] counter and
//! [get it's current value][get_num] or [reset].
//!
//! [increment]: struct.Counter.html#method.increment
//! [decrement]: struct.Counter.html#method.decrement
//! [get_num]: struct.Counter.html#method.get_num
//! [reset]: struct.Counter.html#method.reset

use near_sdk::borsh::{self, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use near_sdk::{env, near_bindgen};

near_sdk::setup_alloc!();

// add the following attributes to prepare your code for serialization and invocation on the blockchain
// More built-in Rust attributes here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html#built-in-attributes-index
#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(Default, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct Counter {
    // See more data types at https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-02-data-types.html
    val: i8, // i8 is signed. unsigned integers are also available: u8, u16, u32, u64, u128
}

#[near_bindgen]
impl Counter {
    /// Returns 8-bit signed integer of the counter value.
    ///
    /// This must match the type from our struct's 'val' defined above.
    ///
    /// Note, the parameter is `&self` (without being mutable) meaning it doesn't modify state.
    /// In the frontend (/src/main.js) this is added to the "viewMethods" array
    /// using near-cli we can call this by:
    ///
    /// ```bash
    /// near view counter.YOU.testnet get_num
    /// ```
    pub fn get_num(&self) -> i8 {
        return self.val;
    }

    /// Increment the counter.
    ///
    /// Note, the parameter is "&mut self" as this function modifies state.
    /// In the frontend (/src/main.js) this is added to the "changeMethods" array
    /// using near-cli we can call this by:
    ///
    /// ```bash
    /// near call counter.YOU.testnet increment --accountId donation.YOU.testnet
    /// ```
    pub fn increment(&mut self) {
        // note: adding one like this is an easy way to accidentally overflow
        // real smart contracts will want to have safety checks
        // e.g. self.val = i8::wrapping_add(self.val, 1);
        // https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i8.html#method.wrapping_add
        self.val += 1;
        let log_message = format!("Increased number to {}", self.val);
        env::log(log_message.as_bytes());
        after_counter_change();
    }

    /// Decrement (subtract from) the counter.
    ///
    /// In (/src/main.js) this is also added to the "changeMethods" array
    /// using near-cli we can call this by:
    ///
    /// ```bash
    /// near call counter.YOU.testnet decrement --accountId donation.YOU.testnet
    /// ```
    pub fn decrement(&mut self) {
        // note: subtracting one like this is an easy way to accidentally overflow
        // real smart contracts will want to have safety checks
        // e.g. self.val = i8::wrapping_sub(self.val, 1);
        // https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i8.html#method.wrapping_sub
        self.val -= 1;
        let log_message = format!("Decreased number to {}", self.val);
        env::log(log_message.as_bytes());
        after_counter_change();
    }

    /// Reset to zero.
    pub fn reset(&mut self) {
        self.val = 0;
        // Another way to log is to cast a string into bytes, hence "b" below:
        env::log(b"Reset counter to zero");
    }
}

// unlike the struct's functions above, this function cannot use attributes #[derive(…)] or #[near_bindgen]
// any attempts will throw helpful warnings upon 'cargo build'
// while this function cannot be invoked directly on the blockchain, it can be called from an invoked function
fn after_counter_change() {
    // show helpful warning that i8 (8-bit signed integer) will overflow above 127 or below -128
    env::log("Make sure you don't overflow, my friend.".as_bytes());
}

/*
 * the rest of this file sets up unit tests
 * to run these, the command will be:
 * cargo test --package rust-counter-tutorial -- --nocapture
 * Note: 'rust-counter-tutorial' comes from cargo.toml's 'name' key
 */

// use the attribute below for unit tests
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use near_sdk::MockedBlockchain;
    use near_sdk::{testing_env, VMContext};

    // part of writing unit tests is setting up a mock context
    // in this example, this is only needed for env::log in the contract
    // this is also a useful list to peek at when wondering what's available in env::*
    fn get_context(input: Vec<u8>, is_view: bool) -> VMContext {
        VMContext {
            current_account_id: "alice.testnet".to_string(),
            signer_account_id: "robert.testnet".to_string(),
            signer_account_pk: vec![0, 1, 2],
            predecessor_account_id: "jane.testnet".to_string(),
            input,
            block_index: 0,
            block_timestamp: 0,
            account_balance: 0,
            account_locked_balance: 0,
            storage_usage: 0,
            attached_deposit: 0,
            prepaid_gas: 10u64.pow(18),
            random_seed: vec![0, 1, 2],
            is_view,
            output_data_receivers: vec![],
            epoch_height: 19,
        }
    }

    // mark individual unit tests with #[test] for them to be registered and fired
    #[test]
    fn increment() {
        // set up the mock context into the testing environment
        let context = get_context(vec![], false);
        testing_env!(context);
        // instantiate a contract variable with the counter at zero
        let mut contract = Counter { val: 0 };
        contract.increment();
        println!("Value after increment: {}", contract.get_num());
        // confirm that we received 1 when calling get_num
        assert_eq!(1, contract.get_num());
    }

    #[test]
    fn decrement() {
        let context = get_context(vec![], false);
        testing_env!(context);
        let mut contract = Counter { val: 0 };
        contract.decrement();
        println!("Value after decrement: {}", contract.get_num());
        // confirm that we received -1 when calling get_num
        assert_eq!(-1, contract.get_num());
    }

    #[test]
    fn increment_and_reset() {
        let context = get_context(vec![], false);
        testing_env!(context);
        let mut contract = Counter { val: 0 };
        contract.increment();
        contract.reset();
        println!("Value after reset: {}", contract.get_num());
        // confirm that we received -1 when calling get_num
        assert_eq!(0, contract.get_num());
    }
}

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are referring to the [Quick-start guide for building smart contracts in Rust](https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/contracts/rust/intro)?

Let's check a few things to make sure you didn't miss any steps.

1. Did you [create a lib.rs file](https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/contracts/rust/intro#creating-librs) and copy the contents of [this smart contract](https://github.com/near-examples/rust-counter/blob/c7ec0fec7a755307a4b95ff960b741597efcd425/contract/src/lib.rs) into that file?
2. Did you successfully [deploy the contract](https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/contracts/rust/intro#deploying-the-contract) using `near-cli` after you compiled it to WASM?
3. Are you [invoking the methods](https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/contracts/rust/intro#increment) using `near-cli` and replacing YOUR_ACCOUNT_HERE with the `testnet` accountId you just deployed the contract to?

If so, would you be able to share your code / commands so I can help you debug your issue? This tutorial was updated recently (less than a month from today) so it should work, but while I'm waiting for your response I will run through the steps to make sure we don't have a bug on our end. :)

** UPDATE **

Just went through the tutorial and it worked for me. Here was my command using `near-cli`:

```sh
near call ex-1.testnet increment --accountId ex-1.testnet
```

And the response:

```
Scheduling a call: ex-1.testnet.increment()
Receipt: 3UTWH43Tgxy1kSSvoax5cRu8A2VEDKZqzgZaEXTwzsBD
    Log [ex-1.testnet]: Increased number to 1
    Log [ex-1.testnet]: Make sure you don't overflow, my friend.
Transaction Id 2U92KghmCqihUuURVaLGj8x8FrBhQ5z1vE35BVdZG1ob
To see the transaction in the transaction explorer, please open this url in your browser
https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/2U92KghmCqihUuURVaLGj8x8FrBhQ5z1vE35BVdZG1ob
```

Feel free to reach out on our [Discord](http://near.chat) for further assistance. The proper channel for this discussion would be `#near-sdk-rs` under `#development` but `#dev-support` is ok too. :)

Comment: can you share your entire lib.rs file? Also, can you share how you are compiling the contract?

Comment: Done! Thanks @Josh Ford

Comment: Hmmmm... Everything looks good with your contract. The only difference is the three backticks at the end of your snippet (```) but I imagine you just added that now for the post right? Your lib.rs doesn't have those in it correct?

The only step left to debug is the compiling process..... Try deleting the compiled WASM file and recompile it using this command:
https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/contracts/rust/intro#compile-the-code

If _that_ doesn't work try deploying your contract to a different accountId and if _that_ doesn't work let's jump on a call and tackle this in real-time. :)

Comment: Thanks! i will follow the same process  on another computer... lets see.

Comment: I follow the same tutorial and use the same commands on another computer and everything its fine... i will try to find the problem.

Comment: LOl i try again just for curiosity... and its working on my first computer. I didnt do anything, wel..l thanks Josh